# I got 404 Error from Google API's via servlet in GAE, but got correct response via browser

Tags: google-app-engine, servlets, google-api

I can get correct response from Google API's via web browser. It is say,
When I access to
https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/4871538073781423026?access_token=XXXXXXXX
by some web browser, then get correct response like

```
{
 "kind": "blogger#blog",
 "id": "4871538073781423026",
 "name": "SoffeeShop",
 "description": "",
 "published": "2012-10-24T23:55:32+09:00",
 "updated": "2015-03-04T14:31:00+09:00",
 "url": "http://soffeeshop.blogspot.com/",
 "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/4871538073781423026",
 "posts": {
  "totalItems": 58,
  "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/4871538073781423026/posts"
 },
 "pages": {
  "totalItems": 0,
  "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/4871538073781423026/pages"
 },
 "locale": {
  "language": "en",
  "country": "",
  "variant": ""
 }
}
```

Although, when I do REST with servlet in GAE, like

```
URL url = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/4871538073781423026?access_token=XXXXXXXXX");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setRequestProperty("X-Appengine-Inbound-Appid", "XXXXX");
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
connection.setRequestProperty("Host", "googleapis.com");
```

or

```
URL url = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/4871538073781423026);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token); 
connection.setRequestProperty("X-Appengine-Inbound-Appid", "XXXXX");
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
connection.setRequestProperty("Host", "googleapis.com");
```

i just got "404 Not Found" Error.

I could get access_token with OAuth2 using same HttpURLConnection in the same servlet in GAE, I could not do access to just Google API's. So, it's mean Http Connections are working well to access to other servers, but it looks like that Google API's deny access from servlet in GAE.

How to access Google API's or Blogger API via servlet in GAE? Please help me.

Comment: Finally, with Blogger API V.3, I could access Blogger API, although I still don't know why I could not use HttpURLConnection.

Thank you so much for answering me :-)

Comment: you also need to provide the API key in your URL i.e https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/2399953?key=YOUR-API-KEY. No need to provide authorization header in case of public blog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to enable blogger API in your GAE project from google developer console it may ask you some question like "how you would like to use the Blogger API?".

Comment: Thanks for answer :-) But I already set the blogger API enable, so I could use it via browser already.

Answer (score 0):

Did you provide the permission to your GAE app to access the Blogger API. I think when you Generate the clientId in your developer console of your app, you have to provide the name of your App in the redirect URIS as http://app-id.appspot.com. i think it will resolve your issue.